# Compiling Android project from terminal

Tags: android, compiler-construction, terminal

I'm experimenting with android terminal emulator([Terminal IDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside)) and trying to compile an Android project. I use the following script to compile.

```
#Build script

#cd into the home dir - this way it works when run from inside vim or any other folder
cd ~/projects/simple_search/

#Clean up
rm -rf build
rm -rf dist

#create the needed directories
mkdir -m 770 -p dist
mkdir -m 770 -p build/classes

#Rmove the R.java file as will be created by aapt
rm src/com/simple/search/R.java 

#Now use aapt
echo Create the R.java file
aapt p -f -v -M AndroidManifest.xml -F ./build/resources.res -I ~/system/classes/android.jar -S res/ -J src/com/simple/search

#cd into the src dir
cd src

#Now compile - note the use of a seperate lib (in non-dex format!)
echo Compile the java code
javac -verbose -cp ../libs/demolib.jar -d ../build/classes \
com/simple/search/AboutDialog.java \
com/simple/search/CustomWindow.java \
com/simple/search/DatabaseHelper.java \
com/simple/search/SearchResults.java \
com/simple/search/SimpleSearch.java \
com/simple/search/SuggestionProvider.java \
com/simple/search/Tag.java \
com/simple/search/TestAction.java \
com/simple/search/TestDetails.java

#Back out
cd ..

#Now into build dir
cd build/classes/

#Now convert to dex format (need --no-strict) (Notice demolib.jar at the end - non-dex format)
echo Now convert to dex format
dx --dex --verbose --no-strict --output=../simple_search.dex org ../../libs/demolib.jar

#Back out
cd ../..

#And finally - create the .apk
apkbuilder ./dist/simple_search.apk -v -u -z ./build/resources.res -f ./build/simple_search.dex 

#And now sign it
cd dist
signer simple_search.apk simple_search_signed.apk

cd ..
```

The script executes fine till `cd build/classes/`. But at `dx --dex --verbose --no-strict --output=../simple_search.dex org ../../libs/demolib.jar` I'm encountering the following error.

```
Now convert to dex format

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org: file not found
        at com.android.dx.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:55)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:139)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:113)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
        at com.spartacusrex.spartacuside.external.dx.main(dx.java:14)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
processing archive ../../libs/demolib.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
processing org/library/libfunc.class...
1 error; aborting
```

What is wrong with the script? Can you point me in the right direction? Any smallest help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove 'org', as it doesn't seem to be a file for your build.
The line should read.

```
dx --dex --verbose --no-strict --output=../simple_search.dex ../../libs/demolib.jar
```

Comment: actually it was replacing org with com. `dx --dex --verbose --no-strict --output=../simple_search.dex com ../../libs/demolib.jar`

Comment: what is the last libs reference for? you have /libs/.. referenced twice y?

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment Sirvon, The final path ../../libs/demolibjar is the path to the input jar file, based on it's location from the script in the original question.
At the root of the project is lib/, where the script compiles the jar, then prior to dexing the working directory is changed to build/classes, hence the need to pop up two levels to get to the lib path.